# Map derived class as an independent one with FNH's Automap

Tags: inheritance, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, automapping

Basically, I have an `ImageMetadata` class and an `Image` class, which derives from `ImageMetadata`. `Image` adds one property: `byte[] Content`, which actually contains binary data.

What I want to do is to map these two classes onto *one* table, but I absolutely do not need NHibernates' inheritance support to kick in. I want to tailor FNH Automap to produce something like:

```
<class name="ImageMetadata" ...>    
    <property name="Name" ... />
    < ... />

<class name="Image" ...>    
    <property name="Name" ... />
    <property name="Content" ... />
    < ... />
```

Is this at all possible?

Currently I have:

```
Override<ImageMetadata>(m => m.Table("Image"))
```

but that still adds a `<joined-subclass>` element to `ImageMetatada`'s mapping.

Comment: Have you got "byte[] Content" automapping?  I wanted to do something similar with arrays of floats, but had to define the properties as IList<float>.  This automaps without any overrides (after a bug in FNH was fixed), but is proving to be inefficient, so I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you will need to alter the [subclassing strategy](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping).  It defaults to table per subclass, whereas what I think you want is table per hierachy.

I think like this:

```
    AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>()
       .Setup(s =>
       {
         s.SubclassStrategy = t => SubclassStrategy.Subclass;
       });
```

Of course, you will have to include a descriminator then, which might not be what you want.  Probably someone with more FNH experience can give a much better answer.

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708061/fluent-nhibernate-automapping-with-discriminator), which deals with a similar problem.